# Is there a good reason to open a SEPARATE WINDOW when user clicks login?

Tags: website-design, window-management

I use Walmart's Bluebird card (basically a pre-paid card which I deposit money in).  When I go to their website (http://bluebird.com) and click "Login", my browser opens a brand new window.  This new window is not JUST for logging in - after I log in it becomes my primary window, and the old window seems to serve no purpose.

Is there some good reason they might have for keeping the original window open, after sending me to a new window/tab (where I remain for all my account access)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's not something made for User Experience (on contrary) but to improve **security**.

---

Imagine this situation.

You're accessing one secure site, home page is not *secure* (it uses HTTP protocol) to greatly reduce server CPU usage (because homepage is requested very often by *random* users and search engines or because it contains non-critical material). You enter your credentials and you login then you're redirected to a HTTPS encrypted connection and now you're sure no one will be able to read or alter your data packets.

However if your network is *unsecure* someone may sniff data you send. This is not a problem with HTTPS because it's encrypted but - do you remember? - you logged in using HTTP and you've redirected to HTTPS after that. If attacker sniffed your credentials (in plain text) then he can effectively act as a *man in the middle*. HTTPS connection is secure **after** it has been initiated, not before.

In this very specific case certificates for homepage and login page are issued to different companies (and I'd guess the one for homepage is a *generic* certificate issued to hosting service provider).

OK but why *new window*? Can't we just reuse existing window/tab and start a new HTTPS session? AFAIK for three reasons:

1) To prevent possible attacks. This topic is out of my knowledge then please refer to [Triple Handshakes and Cookie Cutters: Breaking and Fixing Authentication over TLS](https://secure-resumption.com/tlsauth.pdf).

2) To make *clear* to user that a new secure connection is started. It's maybe the only UX point.

3) To be sure (or greatly reduces chances that) browser bugs and plug-ins loaded by previous pages aren't still loaded in same session/process. Especially if you don't force your users to use latest full-patched browser version then this is main reason to still open a new page nowadays.

EDIT: if we ask ourselves *"is this still required nowadays?"* then answer is probably *"no, **maybe** it's not"* but banks (and company which offers financial services) tends to be little bit conservative about security especially if they don't limit their users to use latest full-patched browser (when they even still have in use Windows XP computer with Internet Explorer 7)...

Comment: Interesting idea.  But in this particular case, the homepage DOES use https (in fact, if I request http version, I get redirected automatically to the https version).

Comment: @loneboat certificates for to homepage and login page are issued to different companies. I'd guess homepage one is generic for hosting service.

Comment: Even in cases like you describe though, why open a separate window?  Why not just direct the user to an https page when they click "Login"?  Note that in this particular page, there is nowhere to enter credentials on the main page - you have to go to a new page anyway to get to the username/password form.  So why open a new window?  (Good point about the separate certificates though - I hadn't noticed that)

Comment: AFAIK for three reasons: 1) to prevent another possible attack based on TLS renegotiation related to _session_ (but here I'm going over my knowledge about security) 2) to make _clear_ to user that a new secure connection is started. 3) I'd also say to be sure browser bugs and plug-ins loaded by previous pages aren't still loaded in same session/process...

Comment: Cool, I consider myself reasonably versed in security, but I didn't know anything about renegotiation attacks!  Thanks for that!

Comment: I have just a vague memory about that, I guess on security.SE there should be an answer. If I'll find a reference I'll update answer.

Comment: The new window is the UX choice. they COULD redirect the user, but probably chose not to in order not to take them away from their original context. The new window/tab/page is there to prevent third parties to interact with their system at data sensitive moments.

Comment: @JotaRMonteiro not ONLY UX choice, there are also technical reasons for that. It became a common practice much before web site designers even start to hear about UX. I didn't understand what you mean with _"The new window/tab/page is there to prevent third parties to interact with their system at data sensitive moments."_

Comment: I don't find this explanation very compelling. If this is true, then wouldn't I expect any site handling sensitive information to do it?  But they don't.  Even when there is a switch from http to https.

Comment: It's annoying (at best) then I see it only for financial sites where they still apply _more is better_ about security.

Comment: If it's a vulnerability in the certificate, https or SSL, there is no explanation why would a new window improve on security...

Comment: @JotaRMonteiro new window is new session, moreover previous pages (in same session/process) may had loaded native plug-ins/active-x. Browser _may_ have vulnerabilities and a native plug-in may keep itself alive for the whole session. I updated answer to make this more clear.

Comment: Yes, sure. But wouldn't a new page suffice for a new session? Isn't the question about the need for a whole new window?

Comment: Generally speaking no. New page will be open on the same session (where new window will not). Moreover new tab/window is often a brand new process then it won't be compromised by any site visited before (for example if one of them loaded - let's say - an ActiveX on Internet Explorer 7...

Comment: Another issue solved with a new page is to make sure the user isn't trapped inside an invisible iframe which could potentially survive the switch to https.

Answer (score 0):

While this is ultimately speculation, I think this was **a design/implentation decision to separate two sites with different purposes**.

- When you are not logged in, you are viewing an advertisement site for the service.
- Once logged in, you access a site that lets you work with your account.

There really isn't any overlap between the two, so they were probably designed as two separate websites with different designs to fit their purposes (I don't have an account, but I assume the site after logging in isn't a single page design, which wouldn't be very usable for managing one's account).

That said, I think **opening a new window was a poor design decision**.  There is no UX rationale for doing so, since someone with an account doesn't need to view the advertisement (and vice versa).  But there are still plenty of cases of unnecessarily opening new windows on the internet, and this is probably one of them.

Comment: I agree with you it's a bad UX choice but it's a (pedantic? maybe) security measure. BTW especially useful for users running on old browsers